# How to Build Superuser.apk

Tags: android, root

I'm trying to rebuild Superuser.apk from CM7 source tree.  After sourcing envsetup.sh, and doing an mm in the Superuser root dir, nothing gets done, with the message "make: nothing to be done for 'all_modules'".  I looked at Android.mk and it appears to me that (maybe) Superuser.apk is copied from prebuilts, yet the full source tree is present.  Can anyone tell me how to re-build Superuser.apk?

My Goal: I want to suppress the "XXX has been granted SuperUser permissions" message.

What I Tried:

1. Added $(BUILD_PACKAGE) to end of Android.mk
   This *did* cause build activity but many errors of type "error: Error: No resource found that matches: the given name: attr 'android:displayOptions' ".

Comment: Maybe try `make -B all_modules` to force the make?

Comment: nope, got message "no rule to make target 'all_modules'. Stop". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the `device.mk` associated to your target platform (samsung, motorola, htc?). I work on pandaboard, then this file lies in `device/ti/panda/device.mk` for me. Then add Superuser to PRODUCT_PACKAGES:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    make_ext4fs \
    com.android.future.usb.accessory \
    annotations \
    Superuser
```

Android will catch that you need this package. Running `mm` afterward in `packages/apps/Superuser` will eventually do what you want. I ran into some [annotation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611043/how-to-make-android-build-system-embed-annotations-jar-in-an-app) on my side, but you might not face those issues...

Answer (score 0):

Duh,
I discovered that I can do what I need using "Preferences" in the stock Superuser app. So my original question, while interesting, is only of academic interest now.

Comment: Ahah, sometimes the truth is right in front of us, not out there Fox Mulder :-)