# How to make android build system embed annotations.jar in an app?

Tags: android, annotations, android-source

I am building [Superuser](https://github.com/ChainsDD/Superuser) on Android Open Source Project 4.0.4. I:

1. fetched the git repo in `packages/apps`,
2. issued `mm` in `packages/apps/Superuser`

and faced following issue:
http://pastebin.com/50vGLhH1

I read that I have to embed `annotations.jar` in android app's dependencies. There are howto do that with eclipse, but cannot find my answer with aosp source code. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will work, do try adding below line in Android.mk

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += annotations
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick: no more annotation error but a brand new error :-). Thanks!

Comment: Well... The brand new error is related actually:
`make: *** No rule to make target out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/annotations_intermediates/javalib.jar', needed by out/target/common/obj/APPS/Superuser_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar'`

Comment: try to find annotations.jar in the out folder, maybe it is built only when sdk is built what you could do is add annotations in the Device.mk PRODUCT_PACKAGES

Comment: I built `sdk/annotations`, seems ok:
`host Java: annotations (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/annotations_intermediates/classes)
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/annotations.jar` but Superuser looks for annotation in `out/target`, not `out/host`.

Comment: I took another way: I commented out each annoying annotation (mostly `@TargetApi`), and rebuilt. I faced a signature problem now: http://pastebin.com/ZR155LRW

Comment: Following https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-x86/Nptu81OD4rw, I changed `LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := superuser` into
`LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := shared` and that made the trick.